# Looking for instructions for this Mega Bloks Dragon Ship

Tags: set-identification, instructions, clone-brands

I don't know the model #, but it's probably from the early 2000's. Looks like this. [image]

Comment: Hi Mariana! Could you please upload a larger picture? This one is 92x92 pixels and thus kind of hard to see.

Comment: I googled a similiar image. The smallest one is the right color, but the one with the red sails is a little better resolution.

Comment: You mean, you didn't take this picture yourself, just found it on the web? Was there any identifying information (i.e. set number, name, year, etc.) with the image?

Comment: https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9895.pdf thank you all for helping so fast!

Comment: This picture looks like one from an ebay listing which means it's copyrighted....

Answer (score 6):

- Looks like *Set #9895 - Dragons - Krystal Wars - Man O War.*

  Instructions: ***[HERE](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9895.pdf)***.

[image]

Comment: That's it! the 9895 Man-O-War. Thank you ! now I just have to find the instructions

Comment: @MarianaArteaga Rin Rio-Oki has updated this answer with a link to the instructions on MegaBlok's site.